# Serialize/deserialize SFML Vectors class using cereal

Tags: c++, serialization, sfml, cereal

I'm using SFML and cereal to serialize/deserialize data and I want to do that for `sf::vector2` and `sf::vector3` class:

**Data.h**

```
#include <SFML\System.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include "cereal-1.2.2\include\cereal\archives\xml.hpp"
#include "cereal-1.2.2\include\cereal\types\map.hpp"

struct DataInfo {
  map<string, sf::Vector2f> vector2FloatData;
  map<string, sf::Vector3f> vector3FloatData;
  map<string, sf::Vector2i> vector2IntData;
  map<string, sf::Vector3i> vector3IntData;

  template <class Archive>
  void serialize(Archive & ar)
  {
     ar(vector2FloatData, vector3FloatData, vector2IntData, vector3IntData);
  }
};
```

**main.cpp**

```
int Main()
{
   std::ofstream file("Test.xml");
   cereal::XMLOutputArchive archive(file);

   DataInfo data;
   archive(data);

   return 0;
}
```

But cereal doesn't know what are `sf::vectors` and i get the following error:

```
Error C2338 cereal could not find any output serialization functions for the provided type and archive combination.
```

I know that exist `CEREAL_REGISTER_TYPE()` but i don't know how to make it work.

Adding to **Data.h**:

```
#include "cereal-1.2.2\include\cereal\types\polymorphic.hpp"

CEREAL_REGISTER_TYPE(sf::Vector2f)
CEREAL_REGISTER_TYPE(sf::Vector3f)
CEREAL_REGISTER_TYPE(sf::Vector2i)
CEREAL_REGISTER_TYPE(sf::Vector3i)
```

I get this error:

```
Error C2338 Attempting to register non polymorphic type.
```

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can't verify if it works, i guess you need to add the serialization for sfml types manually such as:

```
namespace /*cereal*/ sf
{
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & archive, sf::Vector2i & v)
    {
         archive( v.x, v.y);
    }
}
```

Not sure again, yet it may work with templated types too:

```
namespace /*cereal*/ sf
{
    template<class Archive, class Type>
    void serialize(Archive & archive, sf::Vector2<Type> & v)
    {
         archive( v.x, v.y);
    }
}
```

They are not polymorphic types, so you don't need to register anything.

**--EDIT--**

Add the function under *sf* namespace.

Comment: Yes, you'll need something like that, since Cereal won't know how to treat SFML types out of the box.

Comment: Tried but still getting error: Error C2338 cereal could not find any output serialization functions for the provided type and archive combination.

Comment: first try external serialization function with a simple class. then add namespace to your class and try again. finally make it template like sf::vector and try again. i'm sure will find out the problem. Also you need to include cereal before the serialization function.